# Creating package for Mac in Windows / Linux

Tags: linux, macos, r, package

I have trying hard to make a r package myself. I followed the instruction in previous question in stackoverflow on [how to develop package for layman](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).  Here are the steps I tool following the previous question.

1. Run R code in fresh R session

   ```
   # random DNA function
   randDNA = function(n){
   paste(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), n, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
   }
   # DNA to RNA function
   dna2rna <- function(inputStr) {
     if (!is.character(inputStr))
       stop("need character input")
     is = toupper(inputStr)
     chartr("T", "U", is)
   }

   # complementary sequence function
   compSeq <-  function(inputStr){
    chartr("ACTG", "TGAC", inputStr)
    }

   # example data
   dnaseq1 <- c("ATTGTATCTGGGTATTTCCCTTAATTGGGGCCTTT")
   dnaseq2 <- c("TGGGGTAAACCCGGTTTAAAATATATATATTTTT")
   myseqdata <- data.frame(dnaseq1, dnaseq2)
   save(myseqdata, file = "myseqdata.RData")
   ```
2. Install [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) Install R package [utils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html)
3. Pefrom the following task in R

   ```
   require(utils)
   package.skeleton(list = c("randDNA","dna2rna", "compSeq", "myseqdata"), 
   name = "dnatool",environment = .GlobalEnv, path = "c:", force = FALSE)
   ```
4. Edit system environment variable path to following in windows 7

   ```
   C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\perl\bin;C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin; 
   C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.2\bin\x64;
   ```

   (type `>path` in command line to check if the path is properly set.
5. Copy the folder dnatool in step (3) and put in new folder named rpackage, Now change directory to this folder (in DOS)

   ```
   c: \ repackage>  R CMD build dnatool 
   c: \ repackage>  Rcmd build dnatool
   ```

   **Edit: I am sometime getting dnatool.zip but other times dnatool.tar.gx**
6. Checking package in command line (DOS)

   ```
   c: \ repackage> R CMD check dnatool
   ```

I was able to pack it as "dnatool.zip" in windows.

How can compile for MAC or unix source ? What steps are different ?

```
Unix source:     dnatool.tar.gz
Mac OS X binary: dnatool.tgz
```

Do I need Mac computer to do. I do have linux virtualbox and installed ubuntu in it ?

Edit:

Should I use the following commad to get sourcode binary from step (3) folder dnatool ?

```
$ tar -zcvf dnatool.tar.gz/home/dnatool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package that was created using `R CMD build` can be installed on other OS types. Even if your package contains source code other than R (c or c++)  this is the case. Only when you create a binary distribution (I think by adding --binary to the r cmd build call) the package becomes platform specific. The tools needed to build packages are often already installed under linux or mac. So if you create a source distribution, it should work under all the major distributions. To create a mac binary, you need either a mac, or create a cross-compiler environment. The second option could be quite a challenge, I say you could give to a google. Do note that if you upload your package to CRAN, all building of packages is done for you.

Comment: thanks, do you mean "dnatool.zip" can be used in unix environments ?

Comment: "Do note that if you upload your package to CRAN, all building of packages is done for you." what should be loaded to CRAN ? sorry for simple question

Comment: The zip file is a Windows binary, just create a source distribution (tar.gz) and you should be fine under Windows, Mac, or Linux. Do note that in this case the user needs to have the build tools installed. However, under Linux this is often the case, and under Mac and Windows it is quite easy to install them. Once your package is on CRAN (if you plan on that) all these problem go away and users can install it using `install.packages`.

Comment: You can upload a source distribution of your package to an FTP server of CRAN, and if it passes the checks it becomes available in CRAN, making it installable using install.packages. If your package is still experimental, you could also host it on R-forge. This is github/sourceforge/bitbucket-like site for R packages. From R-forge, packages can be installed also directly from the R command line.

Comment: can I just convert dnatool in step (3) just convert to tar.gz. Will it work or can be installed in unix or mac os environments ?

Comment: `R CMD build pkgname` should produce a `tar.gz` file which can be installed under all platforms which support R. So after step 5 you should have a `tar.gz` file, no additional work required. The zipping you perform at the end should not bee needed manually, but is a result of `R CMD build`.

Comment: I am doing in windows and after step 5, I am only getting dnatool.zip not dnatool.tar.gz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10345/discussion-between-paul-hiemstra-and-johnclk)