# Creating a cross-compiler environment to build package binaries

Tags: macos, r, binary, cross-compiling

I have the feeling that this would involve **major** nitty-gritty-details-stuff, nevertheless I'd like to give it a try:

### Actual question

What do I need to do to set up an cross-compiler environment that allows me to build package binaries for platforms **other** than MS Windows (I guess at the moment this would only be Mac OS's `tgz` binaries) **on** MS Windows? The accepted answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259033/creating-package-for-mac-in-windows-linux) suggested that this is possible.

### Background

I have quite a few mac users in my university's beginners R course that don't really know their way around the system specifics of Mac OS and therefore would be overextended with setting up the necessary development tools it takes to compile from source on Mac OS. Therefore, I'd like to offer them a `tgz` binary, but I need to compile on Windows as there's no apple hardware available to me.

Comment: This something I could use? http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: Shouldn't it be so, if you just give them the tar-ball output from `R CMD build` the Mac users should be able to install it by typing `R CMD INSTALL yourPkg.tar.gz`? At least I would assume so that Mac OS is ready configured for that?! You wrote about setting up the development tools is hard in MacOS, but I always thought it is only 'hard' for Windows!?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Well, first of: thanks for removing the "silly question". Second: I tried giving them a `tar.gz` of my package, but R complained about something not being the way Mac OS would expect it. Therefore the question.

Comment: By the way: setting up the development tools on windows is absolutely hassle free thanks to Duncan Murdoch's Rtools: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. If you could tell me what I need to do in Mac OS to put everything I need into place, I'd appreciate a pointer.

Comment: Just to clarify - the 'silly question' was directed to myself, that I considered it to be silly to answer with an own question, I didn't meant your question. Sorry if you felt offended by that!

Comment: @DanielFischer: got it, no problem ;-)

Comment: Well, I need to correct myself: I didn't try `R CMD INSTALL --binary myPkg.tar.gz` but used `install.packages("path/to/mypkg.tar.gz", type="source")` (which failed). That should have the same effect as running `R CMD INSTALL`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought that the `install.packages(...type="sources")` would have done the trick. But have you installed the Xcode developer tools on MacOS? I haven't tried it by myself, but at least I heard that they are required if the source contains code to compile.

Comment: No, that's the thing I hoped to get around. Plus I've read that the Xcode tools aren't free of charge anymore: http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-packages-from-source-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I just googled a bit and found that the Xtools 3 are still for free - and that they are sufficient to install a tar-ball with sources (check this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-packages-from-source-on-mac-os-x/) . But - if you want to avoid them, then it is anyway no option for you, sorry.

Comment: One other option would be - if you have access to a MacOS image you could set up a virtual machine on your own computer, install MacOS to it, and compile then directly there on MacOS the binaries and  distribute them later to your students. That way only you have to set up the correct environment.

Comment: @DanielFischer: awesome! Haven't thought of virtual machines yet! That's sounds like the best alternative at the moment, thanks!

Comment: All you need on OS X is the xcode command line tools, which ARE free and can be downloaded separately (although you do need an apple account). That will be much easier than setting up a cross-compilation environment in windows (which I suspect will be next to impossible)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Hadley. I'll just got myself some mac hardware for testing purposes and will checkout how everything runs after `xcode` is available